# Perforce, How to integrate a change to another branch?

Tags: branch, perforce, branching-and-merging

I have trunk and a release branch.  If I fixed a bug in release branch, I definitely should integrate the fix back to trunk. However, I didn't find a command dedicated to integrate such a single change list; did I miss something?

Comment: Do you want to just apply all changes made on the release branch back to trunk, or do you need to pick and choose particular changelists ?

Comment: I just need to integrate a single changelist, thx

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To integrate changelist 100, for example, you'd use:

```
p4 merge //releasebranch/...@=100 //trunk/...
p4 resolve
p4 submit
```

(If you have an older Perforce server you'll have to use 'integ' instead of 'merge'.)

Note that '@=100' means the same thing as '@100,100' in this context.

Answer (score 5):

I have used this:

```
p4 integrate -c 625466 //SrcPath/...@622912,@622912 //DestPath/...
```

Where CL 622912 is the one we want to integrate, and CL 625466 is the new CL.

Comment: After p4 integrate i had to do 
"p4 resolve" to get the changes