# Integrating multiple changelists on perforce

Tags: version-control, perforce, perforce-branch-spec

I have a list of changelists to be merged from the trunk to branch.

Is there a way to automate integrating multiple changelists in perforce ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can integrate a single change by doing:

```
p4 integrate //depot/source/...@CLN1,CLN1 //depot/destination/...
```

And you then can integrate additional changes on top of that before submitting:

```
p4 integrate //depot/source/...@CLN2,CLN2 //depot/destination/...
p4 integrate //depot/source/...@CLN3,CLN3 //depot/destination/...
```

It should be easy for you to write a script that loops over a list of change numbers and executes the appropriate `p4 integrate` command for each one.

Comment: That syntax failed for me. The correct way to do this today is with the suffix `@=1000`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12149115/418362.

Comment: @Artfunkel As far as I know, this is still the correct way to do it.  I don't know why that syntax would fail for you. (What error did you get?) `p4 help revisions` still describes using a comma (how else would you specify a *range*?), and the `@=` syntax usually refers to a shelved changeset. (FWIW, I'm using p4 2004.1.)

Comment: Ah, I was using `#` instead of `@`. That would probably be the reason!